# Laravel pass param on blade

Tags: javascript, laravel, laravel-blade

I have to pass a javascript variable (id) in the laravel route.

```
var id = this.value;
window.location.href = '{{route("admin",id)}}';
```

this method is wrong! help Me!
thank you

Comment: If you know the URL you want to navigate to, just write it like this: `window.location.href = '/my/route/' + id`

Comment: Hi, I can't use url like this.

Comment: what url should you have for the route admin, show me?

Comment: Try `"{!!  (url('admin')) !!}/"+id`